# Unable to locate WindowID

Tags: eclipse, selenium, popup, window

I am currently testing a web app using selenium rc with eclipse. I've been having issues with a single pop up window which appears when a submit button is clicked. The confirmation window appears with a single 'ok' option.

I've also tried 'chooseOKonnextConfirmation' in conjunction with .getConfirmation but eclipse tells me no confirmation exists. I've tried inspecting the window itself with firebug but have been unable to get any results.

I also tried with "selenium.selectWindow(getAllWindowIDs ()[1]);" but selenium not recognizing "getAllWindowIDs".

Could somebody please tell me how I can retrieve the windowID and the associated API commands I need to implement to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

from your description, i understand that you have an ALERT window being appeared after clicking SUBMIT button but not the CONFIRMATION window.

if my understanding is correct

( you said single OK button - ALERT window appears with single OK button - CONFIRMATION window appears with OK and CANCEL buttons - there is another window javascript can generate which is CONFIRMATION.it appears with TEXT field and OK and CANCEL buttons )

so you must use accordingly.

here is what you should use

if(selenium.isAlertPresent()) {
 String message = selenium.getAlert();
}

this will consume you Alert window and you can check the message displayed on Alert window if you want.

if this is not please post write your comment

Answer (score 0):

It's `selenium.getAllWindowIds()`; note the capitalisation.  Don't forget to make sure the popup has already appeared (e.g. `selenium.waitForPopUp()`).

Answer (score 0):

Yes sudarsan is correct if you have an alert.

If you have an popup window not an alert with OK button then you have to click OK when popup appears.

If you are unable to locate the button use firebug to locate the element.